# crunchbase api not working, after a lot of research determined may be deprecated, but dont know how to make the changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, database, api

I have a JS Fiddle of it, the search is not working. I think it is because of deprecation, but I have seen and read through the documentation for the current version which is 3.1 and it does not work after I implement the changes

I tried to google and look for videos all over youtube on tutorials for the version 3.1 and tried changing the code around here and there.

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600,700,800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="searchcontainer"> 
    <div id="search">
        <input placeholder="enter name"></input>
        <div id="source">Powered by Crunchbase</div>
    </div>
    </div>
<div id="form">     
    <div id="desc"></div>
    <div id="results"></div>
    <div id="total"></div>
    <div id="acquired"></div>
    <div id="comp"></div>
</div>




var key = '854yf2awd662y74jfqd6kru5';
var company = '';

$('input').keypress(function (e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
        clearFields();
        getDetails($(this).val());
    }
});

function clearFields() {
    $('#desc').html('');
    $('#results').html('');
    $('#total').html('');
    $('#acquired').html('');
    $('#comp').html('');
    $('#desc').html('<div style="width: 100%; text-align: center;"><img src="https://shop.septa.org/skins/SEPTA/customer/images/snake_transparent.gif"/><br/>Loading</div>');
};

function getDetails(co) {
    company = co;
    var url = "https://api.crunchbase.com/v3.1/organizations?user_key=854yf2awd662y74jfqd6kru5"
    $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
        var output = '<h3>Funding Rounds</h3>';
        var competition = '<h3>Competitors</h3><ul>';
        var total_raised = 0;
        console.log(data); 
        for (var i in data.funding_rounds) {
            output += '<ul id="dates"><li>';
            output += dateFormat(data.funding_rounds[i].funded_month, data.funding_rounds[i].funded_day,data.funding_rounds[i].funded_year);
            output += '</li></ul><ul id="amounts"><li>';
            output += numberWithCommas(data.funding_rounds[i].raised_amount);
            output += '</li></ul>';
            total_raised += data.funding_rounds[i].raised_amount;
        }
        $('#desc').html('<h3>'+ data.description + '</h3><h4>'+data.overview+'</h4><h5>' + data.homepage_url + '</h5><h5>est. ' + dateFormat(null, null, data.founded_year) + '</h5>');
        $('#results').html(output);
        $('#total').html(numberWithCommas(total_raised));
        if(data.acquisition == null) {
            if(data.deadpooled_year == null) {
                if(data.ipo == null) {
                    $('#acquired').html('<span style="color: rgba(0,120,255,1)">Alive and kickin\'</span>');
                } else {
                    $('#acquired').html(data.ipo.stock_symbol + '<br/>' + dateFormat(null, null, data.ipo.pub_year) + '<br/>' + numberWithCommas(data.ipo.valuation_amount));
                }
            } else {
                $('#acquired').html('<span style="color: red">Deadpool</span>');
            }
        } else {
            $('#acquired').html('Acquired by ' + data.acquisition.acquiring_company.name + '<br/>' + numberWithCommas(data.acquisition.price_amount));
        }
        for (var j in data.competitions) {
            competition += '<li>'+data.competitions[j].competitor.name+'</li>';
        }
        competition += '</ul>';
        $('#comp').html(competition);
        styles();
    })
    .fail(function(){
        $('#desc').html('No Results Found');
    });  
};

function numberWithCommas(x) {
    if(x == null) {
        return '';
    } else {
        return '$' + x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
    }
}

function dateFormat(m,d,y) {
    if(d == null) {
        if(m == null) {
            if(y == null) {
                return '';
            } else {
                return y;
            }
        } else {
            if(y == null) {
                return '';
            } else {
                return m + '/' + y;
            }
        } 
    } else {
        if(m == null) {
            return '';
        } else {
            if(y == null) {
                return m + '/' + d;
            } else {
                return m + '/' + d + '/' + y;
            }
        }
    }
}

function styles() {
    $('#comp li').click(function() {
        clearFields();
        $('input').val($(this).html());
        getDetails($(this).html().toLowerCase());
    });
    var h4Height = $('#desc h4').height();
    $('#desc h4').css({
        'height': '130px'
    });
    $('#desc h4')
    .mouseenter(function(){
        $(this).css('height', Math.min(Math.max(h4Height+10,130),400) + 'px');
        $('body').css('overflow','hidden');
        $('body').animate({
            'scrollTop': 0
        }, 500);
    })
    .mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).css('height','130px');
        $('body').css('overflow','auto');
        $(this).animate({
            'scrollTop': 0 
        },500);
    });
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if($(this).scrollTop() > 10) {
            $('#searchcontainer').css({
                'box-shadow': '2px 0px 10px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.1)'
            });
            $('input').css({'border-bottom':'0px'});
        } else {
            $('#searchcontainer').css({
                'box-shadow': '2px 0px 10px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0)'
            });
            $('input').css({'border-bottom':'1px solid #ccc'});
        }
    });
}
```

Actual result is no search results comes up upon submitting the search term.

Expected result is to have search results show up upon pressing enter

Here is the JS FIDDLE I am working with.Any help is appreciated! Thanks!!

http://jsfiddle.net/myh2002/f8Pn4/12/

Comment: When you make the request to the API, their website redirects you to an HTML document. So no JSON. You need to use the v2 API.

Comment: Hi @ChrisG, thanks for your response but the v2 API is directing me to a page that does not work and asks for an access code

http://static.crunchbase.com/api/api_deprecation.html